# Tasm can't locate include file

Tags: assembly, tasm

In my `program.asm` I include file with the tasm directive

```
include "file.asm"
```

however I get an error "Can't locate file file.asm". The file is in the same directory as the source code which is D:\source. Tasm is in directory `D:\tasm`. I tried to create file `TASM.CFG` in the `tasm/bin` directory with the line `/iD:\source` but that didn't help. I also tried to move the `file.asm` into the `tasm/bin` directory, that also didn't help. I also tried to specify the full path in the include directive

```
include "D:\source\file.asm"
```

that also didn't help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `MASM` syntax for include is simply `include file.asm` i.e. without the quotes.
AFAIK MASM is the default mode for TASM

Reference page 37 and 39 of the [TASM 5 users guide](http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_Version_5_Users_Guide.pdf)